# Is there anyway to remove the dots for points from angularjs charts

Tags: angularjs, chart.js, angular-chartist.js

[image]

Can we remove these dots for points so that it looks like a straight line. Although i can see that there is an option in charts.js unable to implement here

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do this with

```
options: { elements: { point: { radius: 0 } } }
```